# Regex date match: "27 January 1756" in "Date of death\n27 January 1756" without also returning the "Date of death" part of string

Tags: python, regex

Suppose the following string is given:

```
stri = "Date 26 March 1256\nDate of death\n27 January 1756\n25 January 1567\n death"
```

Now I only want to extract the date immediately after `Date of death`, namely `27 January 1756`.

I got this far:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"Date of death.*?[0-9][0-9]? [A-z]+ [0-9]{4}", re.DOTALL)
>>> print regex.findall(stri)
['Date of death\n27 January 1756']
```

But I'd like to get only `27 January 1756` in one regex search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group (parenthesis) around the part of the match you want `findall` to return:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"Date of death.*?([0-9][0-9]? [A-z]+ [0-9]{4})", re.DOTALL)
>>> print regex.findall(stri)
['27 January 1756']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookbehind instead:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=Date of death\n)[0-9][0-9]? [A-z]+ [0-9]{4}", re.DOTALL)
```

This will check whether the current position is preceded by `Date of death\n` without actually including it in the match.

Note that you cannot use `.*?` now, because variable-length lookbehinds are not supported by most regex engines.

You can also shorten your regex a bit by using the built-in character class `\d`:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=Date of death\n)\d{1,2} [A-z]+ \d{4}", re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capture groups.

```
regex = re.compile(r"Date of death (.*?[0-9]{1,2} [A-z]+ [0-9]{4})", re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
In [64]: m=re.search("(?<=Date of death)\s+(\d+ \w+ \d+)",stri)

In [65]: m.groups()
Out[65]: ('27 January 1756',)

In [66]: m.groups()[0]
Out[66]: '27 January 1756'
```